# PyCharm / PyQt: How to obtain code completion with dynamically loaded ui files

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm

Let's say I have a ui file created in Qt Designer that I want to load dynamically to then manipulate the widgets, such as:

**example.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('example.ui', self)

        # No code completion here for self.myPushButton:
        self.myPushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClick)

        self.show()
```

**Is there a standard / convenient way of enabling code completion for the widgets loaded this way in PyCharm (2017.1.4)?**

At the moment I am using this (written in the constructor after the ui file is loaded):

```
self.myPushButton = self.myPushButton  # type: QtWidgets.QPushButton
# Code completion for myPushButton works at this point
```

I also thought of this, but it does not seem to do the trick:

```
assert isinstance(self.myPushButton, QtWidgets.QPushButton)
# PyCharm does not even recognise myPushButton as an attribute of self at this point
```

Finally, I also thought of using python stubs, such as:

**example.pyi:**

```
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myPushButton: QtWidgets.QPushButton = ...
```

However, myPushButton is properly recognised in code outside example.py but not in code inside example.py itself, which is kind of the opposite of what I wanted.

I am also considering taking my first approach but with all those lines put in a private method that will never get called, such as:

**example.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('example.ui', self)

        # Code completion now works here for self.myPushButton:
        self.myPushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClick)

        self.show()

    def __my_private_method_never_called():
        self.myPushButton = self.myPushButton  # type: QtWidgets.QPushButton

        # Or even this (it should have the same effect if this
        # function is never called, plus it is less verbose):
        self.myPushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()

        # If I want to make sure that this is never called
        # could raise an error at some point:
        raise YouShouldNotHaveCalledThisError()
```

This seems to work fine, and it also allows me to group all my type hinting code together, isolated from the rest. I could even make some script to write all those lines for me by parsing the ui files. I am just wondering if people reading my code would find this approach very unorthodox, even if I comment clearly why am I writing a technically useless private function.

Comment: Pycharm is not able to recognize the .ui file

Answer (score 7):

If anybody is interested, I made the script I mentioned to parse the .ui files and generate stub code ready to be copied to my class:

**ui_stub_generator.py:**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree


def generate_stubs(file):
    root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(file).getroot()
    print('Stub for file: ' + os.path.basename(file))
    print()
    print('    def __stubs(self):')
    print('        """ This just enables code completion. It should never be called """')

    for widget in root.findall('.//widget'):
        name = widget.get('name')
        if len(name) > 3 and name[:2] == 'ui' and name[2].isupper():
            cls = widget.get('class')
            print('        self.{} = QtWidgets.{}()'.format(
                name, cls
            ))

    print('        raise AssertionError("This should never be called")')
    print()


def main():
    for file in sys.argv[1:]:
        generate_stubs(file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This only parses widgets whose names start with 'ui' followed by an uppercase letter, such as 'uiMyWidget', which is the naming convention that I typically follow in the Qt Designer. By doing this, the widgets with names automatically generated by the Qt Designer are ignored (if I cared about these, I would have given them a proper name). It should be straightforward to update this for any other naming conventions, or other type of objects, such as actions.

For convenience, I have set this up as an external tool in PyCharm as well; see screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jPET.png) (change the paths as appropriate). That way, I only have to right-click my ui file in the project window, then *External Tools -> Stub Generator for Qt UI Files*, and I get the following output in the Run window ready to be copied:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe D:\MyProject\bin\ui_stub_generator.py D:\MyProject\my_ui_file.ui
Stub for file: my_ui_file.ui

    def __stubs(self):
        """ This just enables code completion. It should never be called """
        self.uiNameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.uiOpenButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.uiSplitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
        self.uiMyCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.uiDeleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        raise AssertionError("This should never be called")

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: That's a great idea. I had the same issue of ui file not recognized by autocompletion. I didn't think of that. Your inclusion of the script in external tools is also welcome. I take it for my own use. Thank you.

Comment: @StephanePiriou just to give you a bit more ideas: in addition to show the `__stubs` method in console, the final version my script checks for a Python file / class with the same name (e.g. `my_ui_file.py` / `MyUiFile`) and replaces that method directly. Then, I am using a `.ui` file watcher to execute the script automatically. I did this at work so I cannot show it here, but I will edit my answer with a simplified version at some point

Comment: @FenAndr where then the stub code will be added? In a separate .pyi file? PyCharm doesn't seem to index it..

Comment: @maicol07 in the normal `.py` file, somewhere inside the class itself. Unless the latest PyCharm version has dramatically changed in this regard, this solution should still work. AFAIK, `.pyi` files are only used for external code accessing your class, not within the class itself, and hence cannot be used for this.

Comment: @FernAndr I'm actually trying PySide2 so I'm writing code without classes at the moment, only in the main. Should I change self variables to my window variable?

Comment: @maicol07 In that case, perhaps replacing `def __stubs(self):` with `if False:` and all `self` references to `window` as you say might to the trick. Otherwise, I would suggest wrapping your window in a custom class (similar to the `example.py` file in my original question) and put the stub method there.